# Implementation of word counting on non-text-based file as wc in Linux in C++

Tags: c++, linux, logic

I am recently working on implementing word counting as wc in Linux in C++. I've read a lot of posts about how to implement this function, but I've still got a problem. When I use text-based file as the input, it'll return right word counts. Otherwise, it returns incorrect counts. So I am wondering if the logic of my code is wrong. I really can't figure this out. Please help me solve this problem.

What I expected is to get the exact number of word counts as wc does, for example:

```
wc -w filename
```

it'll return

```
wordCounts filename
```

I want to get the exactly same number of wordCounts as wc does and return as the result of function.

I've used .cpp and .txt files as input, and I got right word count.But when I use .out or other files it returns different result.

Here's my code:

```
int countWords()
  {
    std::ifstream myFile(pathToFile);
    char buffer[1];
    enum states {WHITESPACE,WORD};
    int state = WHITESPACE;
    int wordCount = 0;

    if(myFile.is_open())
    {
      while(myFile.read(buffer,1))
      {
        if(!isspace(buffer[0]))
        {
          if (state == WHITESPACE )
          {
            wordCount++;
            state = WORD;
          }

        }
        else
        {
          state = WHITESPACE;
        }

      }

      myFile.close();

    }
    else
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("File has not opend");
    }

    return wordCount;

  }
```

Comment: How do you define a word on a non-text (meaning, it's wrong relative to  what)?

Comment: Please chose `C`or `C++` this is not the same

Comment: Can you show sample input of non-text, the desired output and explain how the counting should work, compared to the actual output you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If your program is written in C++, please do not include the C tag.  It will get you downvotes very fast.

Comment: If you're getting the wrong values, there's a decent chance that plain `char` is a signed type, and the binary data includes negative character codes (bytes with the high bit set, or in the range 0x80..0xFF in unsigned char notations).  The `isspace()` function doesn't work correctly when not given an `unsigned char` or `EOF` as the argument (most negative values are out of range).

Comment: The question may be a bit unclear.The text file I mean is like .txt or .cpp that can be opened by text editor.Otherwise like a.out is non-text-based file in my acknowledgment.I am relative new to programming, so my expression might be unclear.Sorry for that :(

Comment: Why is `pathToFile` not an argument to the function?  Global variables are anathema (mostly).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Because I am building a program simulating file system in Linux.The class containing this function is used as a node.So sometimes it returns its path if needed.So I let path be a global variable. And what I expect is that this function will return word counts like wc command in linux:

wc filename

(line count) (word count) (byte count)  filename

I want to get the exact same number of word count  as wc does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't obvious at all, but on a Mac (so it might not apply to Linux, but I expect it does), I can get the same result as `wc` by using `setlocale(LC_ALL, ""):` before calling your counting function.

The other problem is, as I noted in a comment, that `isspace()` takes an integer in the range 0..255 or EOF, but when you get signed values from plain `char`, you are indexing out of range and you get whatever you get (it is undefined behaviour).  Without the `setlocale()` call, the character codes 9 (tab, `'\t'`), 10 (newline, `'\n'`), 11 (vertical tab, `'\v'`), 12 (formfeed, `'\f'`), 13 (carriage return, `'\r'`) and 32 (space, `' '`) are treated as 'space' by `isspace()`.  When the `setlocale()` function is called on the Mac, the character code 160 (NBSP — non-breaking space) is also counted as a space, and that brings the calculation into sync with `wc`.

Here's a mildly modified version of your function which counts lines and characters as well as words.  The function is revised to take a file name argument — you may do as you wish with yours, but you should avoid global variables whenever possible.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <clocale>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int countWords(const char *pathToFile)
{
    std::ifstream myFile(pathToFile);

    char buffer[1];
    enum states { WHITESPACE, WORD };
    int state = WHITESPACE;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int cc = 0;
    int lc = 0;

    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        while (myFile.read(buffer, 1))
        {
            cc++;
            if (buffer[0] == '\n')
                lc++;
            if (!isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[0])))
            {
                if (state == WHITESPACE)
                {
                    wordCount++;
                    state = WORD;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                state = WHITESPACE;
            }
        }
        myFile.close();
        std::cerr <<   "cc = " << cc << ", lc = " << lc
                  << ", wc = " << wordCount << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("File has not opened");
    }

    return wordCount;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::cout << countWords("/dev/stdin") << "\n";
}
```

When compiled (from `wc79.cpp` into `wc79`), and run on itself, I get the output:

```
$ ./wc79 < wc79
cc = 13456, lc = 6, wc = 118
118
$ wc wc79
       6     118   13456 wc79
$
```

The two are now in agreement.

Comment: Wow,that's a very clear solution.You really did me a BIG favor, and it works perfectly fine now.Thanks for your help!!!